# Center aligning text in a select menu

Tags: css

I have a ddl in my menu and wish to center the text. Because the ddl selected values are different lengths, they go off center. Any help appreciated.

I've tried text-indent as in the example below.

```css
select {
  font-weight: bold;
  color:#fff;
  background:#444444;
  border:0;
  text-indent: 20%;
  font-size:18px;
  height:29px;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="0">Mixed Job Lot</option>
  <option value="1">Antiques / Art</option>
  <option value="2">Baby &amp; Toddler Stuff</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Not really an asp.net question. You could create this as normal html/css in a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to demonstrate exactly what you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `text-align-last:center;` to your select option

```css
select {
  font-weight: bold;
  color:#fff;
  background:#444444;
  border:0;
  font-size:18px;
  height:29px;
  text-align-last:center;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="0">Mixed Job Lot</option>
  <option value="1">Antiques / Art</option>
  <option value="2">Baby &amp; Toddler Stuff</option>
</select>
```

Comment: beware this won’t work in Safari and iOS

Comment: yes, i know that, for more info go to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last link

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in Chrome latest on Win10 either: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lx2m9.png

Comment: bro we are talking about select not option